# How can i make webpack.config.babel.js work?

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I've searched a lot solutions about this problem but none worked,
and here is my current local environment and file structure (I just want to test if babel.js works thus there is no "src").

**webpack: 4.41.2**
**nodejs: 12.13.1**

- my_work_dir

  - .babelrc
  - package.json
  - webpack.config.babel.js

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  ...,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/register": "^7.8.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.babel.js

```js
export default {}
```

and then when i run "webpack" in my shell , an error came

[image]

Comment: I'm having this same problem too. What's weird is that I got a little bit further when I accidentally added an extra dot to the name "webpack.config..babel.js". There was an other error after that, about something found in a .map file, but I got past an error about an "import" statement (probably the same issue you were having with "export").